# SELECT con detalle de meses (tanto existentes como no existentes)

Tags: mysql

Actualmente estoy utilizando dos tablas "vehiculos"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y "gastos"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de las cuales intento generar un detalle por mes del total gastos de cada vehiculo entre un rango de fechas, para ello he realizado la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT v.vehiculo, SUM(g.total), MONTHNAME(g.fecha), YEAR(g.fecha) FROM vehiculos v INNER JOIN gastos g ON v.idvehiculo = g.idvehiculo WHERE g.fecha BETWEEN '2017-12-01' AND '2018-04-01'
GROUP BY v.vehiculo,MONTHNAME(g.fecha), YEAR(g.fecha)
```

La cual me devuelve los siguientes valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo algunos vehiculos como por ejemplo "Metro" y "Riviera" no poseen gastos registrados para el mes de "Febrero" me gustaria mostrar esos meses donde no hubieron registros con un valor "0.00" de forma que todos los vehiculos tengan el mismo intervalo de meses tengan o no gastos registrados para dicho mes.

¡Agradezco vuestra ayuda de antemano!

Comment: Tenes que crear una tabla de calendario y joinearla con esta si lo queres dentro de la base. si es para un front end, tranquilamente se puede hacer en el sin agregar nada mas.